# How to return flag and result from a funcion (python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, return

Let's see code first-

```
def findlinks():
    mylinks=[]
    if (condition):
        for x in range(int):
            if x==(int):
               #some operation goes here
            else:
                 #some operation goes here
                return mylinks,1        

    else:
        for x in range(int):
           if x==(int):
              #some operation goes here
                    return mylinks,0

           else:
                #some operation goes here
 links=[]    
 while (True):
        first,second=findlinks()
        links=links+first
        if second==1:
                 pass
        elif second ==0:
                  break
```

The problem is in `while loop`. It never runs multiple times. I think it is because  when I return from `function` it gets out of `function` as well as `loop`.

Any alternative way to tackle this ? or any modification to code?

Comment: @TomKarzes Does it will not wait for result from function. While loop is out of function.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread it.  Well then the `while` loop will break when `second` is equal to `0`.

Comment: I would appreciate it more if you can mention the objective of your code. Your code is more like pseudocode and it is difficult to identify the purpose. Keep in mind that the call to your function must return the appropriate `second` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what is it exactly that you want to achieve.

If you want to return after the loop is finished you can do this:

```py
def func():
    list = []
    if condition:
        flag = 1
        # loop here, do something with the list
    else:
        flag = 0
        # loop here, do something with the list

    return list, flag
```